# bootstrap и динамическое добавление вкладок

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

есть вот такая разметка

```
  <!-- Навигация -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" id="navtabs">
  </ul>
  <!-- Содержимое вкладок -->
  <div class="tab-content" id="tabcontent">
  </div>
```

есть вот такой скрипт

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#navtabs').empty();
        $('#tabcontent').empty();
        $.each(myArray, function(i, v)
        {
            $('#navtabs').append('<li class="nav-item"><a href="#' + v + '" role="tab" data-toogle="tab" class="nav-link" id="tabh' + i + '">' + v + '</li>');
            $('#tabcontent').append('<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="' + v + '">' + v + '</div>');
        });

        $('#tabh0').tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

То есть смысл в том, чтобы вкладки и их содержимое сформировались на основании массива. И они сформировались, но не работают как надо.

```
$('#tabh0').tab('show');
```

Открывает первую вкладку

Если в консоли я напишу

```
$('#tabh1').tab('show');
```

откроется вторая вкладка.

Но по клику они не меняются. Помогите исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap.js` навешивает обработчики кликов в своем `$(document).ready`, который выполняется до Вашего - когда Ваших ссылок еще нет.

```
$('#navtabs a').click(function(){
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

> `$('#navtabs').empty();` просто очищает содержимое контейнера. В
>   данном случае список вкладок. Но ведь снова же создаю. Динамически.
>   Почему события не вешаются сами?

Во время загрузки страницы происходит следующее.

Загружается и исполняется `bootstrap.js`. Во время это "исполнения" прикрепляются обработчики к `$(document).ready`.

Загружается Ваш скрипт со своим `$(document).ready`.

Загружается исходный html.

jQuery начинает по порядку вызывать обработчики `$(document).ready`.

В бутстраповском `$(document).ready` происходит инициализация табов - существующих в DOM-e в данный момент, в том числе навешивание на них обработчиков кликов.

Выполняется Ваш `$(document).ready` - удаляются табы (если они есть - вместе с обработчиками кликов) и создаются новые табы - без обработчиков.

Comment: Я сейчас попробую. Но я же говорил, что по запросу tab('show') все получается. Мне интересно почему это без явного указания не работает. Ведь когда я создаю вкладки статически, мне не нужно вызывать tab('show'). Почему так?

Comment: Потому что `bootstrap.js` навешивает аабсолютно такие же обработчики кликов в своем `$(document).ready`, который выполняется до Вашего.

Comment: А при динамическом добавлении табов не навешивает что ли?

Comment: И при динамическом навешивает, только у Вас их в тот момент нет (или Вы их удаляете - `$('#navtabs').empty();`), а позднее Ваш код создает их без обработчиков.

Comment: Так само собой я их удаляю. `$('#navtabs').empty();` просто очищает содержимое контейнера. В данном случае список вкладок. Но ведь снова же создаю. Динамически. Почему события не вешаются сами?